# I am trying to make a div disappear on click and make another div appear in its place I have wrote and run code using javascript;

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
document.getElementById("nextOneButton").onclick = function(){

    document.getElementById("mainFrameOne").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("mainFrameTwo").visibility="visible";

}

//mainFrameTwo is initially set hidden in terms of visibillity
//nextOneButton is on top of the mainFrameOne in terms of position, when //clicked it should move to next frame. Some what like a slide show
```

Comment: What is the error that you are experiencing? However, without knowing your error, I can already tell you that visibility and display are 2 different css properties.

Comment: Please share your sample html

Answer (score 1):

Really you need a button so you can bind your function to the onclick event. Here is a possible solution:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function myFunction() { 
 document.getElementById("mainFrameOne").style.display="none"; 
 document.getElementById("mainFrameTwo").style.display="block"; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainFrameOne">
    <p>mainFrameOne</p>
</div>
<div id="mainFrameTwo" style="display:none;">
    <p>mainFrameTwo</p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could use anchor tags to remove the need for the button:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function myFunction() { 
 document.getElementById("mainFrameOne").style.display="none"; 
 document.getElementById("mainFrameTwo").style.display="block"; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="mainFrameOne" onclick="myFunction()" href="#">
    mainFrameOne
</a>
<a id="mainFrameTwo" href="#" style="display:none;">
    mainFrameTwo
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried both the button and anchor tags but they result in the same thing. The mainframeone dissapears but the the mainframetwo does not appear

Comment: So when you click the button / anchor tag you do not see the text 'mainFrameTwo'?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div id ="activeContent" >


                <div id ="mainFrameOne"> <!-- POSITION MATTERS WHEN YOU WANT TO DO THE DISSAPEARING ACT WITH JAVASCRIPT -->

                    <img src="person.gif" id ="person" width="1350" height ="900">

                    <div id ="backOneButton"> <h4 class ="directionButtonsText">   Back  </h4> </div>

                    <div id ="nextOneButton"> <h4 class ="directionButtonsText">   Next   </h4> </div>

                    <div id = "mainFrameOneTitleBar">

                        <h3 id ="jakesLemonade">Jake's Lemonade Stand</h3>

                    </div> <!-- End of MainFrameTitleBar -->

                    <h3 id = "firstTextJake"> This is Jake, the owner of a small lemonade stand.<br> Like many other small business owners, Jake wants to know <br>what the future holds for him. CloudFin can tell him exactly that. </h3>

                </div> <!-- End of MainFrameOne Div-->


                <div id ="mainFrameTwo"> 

                    <div id ="backTwoButton"> <h4 class ="directionButtonsText">   Back  </h4> </div>

                    <div id ="nextTwoButton"> <h4 class ="directionButtonsText">   Next   </h4> </div>

                    <div id = "mainFrameTwoTitleBar">

                        <h3 id ="lemsLemons">When life gives you lemons, Make lemonade</h3>

                        <script type="text/javascript">


                        </script>

                    </div> <!-- End of MainFrameTitleBar -->

                    <h3 id = "secondTextJake"> How much does each lemon cost?</h3>

                </div> <!-- End of MainFrameTwo -->



        </div> <!-- End of ActiveContent Div -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If something is not working you can consider using addEventListener.
Example:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', changeVisibility(), null);
function changeVisibility()
{
    document.getElementById('divToHide').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('divToShow').style.display = "block";
}
```